# Time machine cannot backup after initial backup on samsung T7

Tags: backup, time-machine, ssd

I'm running macOS 10.14.6. I successfully backed up using time machine to my Samsung SSD T7 five months ago but I cannot backup to it when I tried using time machine now.

I get the "preparing backup" stage but then time machine stops the backup. When I check my hard drive, I do get updated .inProgress file.

I have already tried to delete the .inProgress file and restart but it fails every time. The .inProgress file is less than 1 MB when it fails.

I have already run disk utility on my T7 and it backed up before. Is there a way perhaps to see if the backup is failing due to a specific file?